# Filtering Query not Running right

Tags: laravel

When filtering categories, the query is not running properly. Any ideas?
it is still showing me all posts even though the I'm using the right URL with GET Data in it.
The search function is working however.

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)

{
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, function ($query, $search) {

        $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
    });



    $query->when(
        $filters['category'] ?? false,
        function ($query, $category) {
            $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('slug', $category);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't know if `whereHas` will work within a `when` callback. Try a normal `if`

Comment: `whereHas` will work within a `when` callback. That's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be `orWhere` I guess.

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, function ($query, $search) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%{$search}%");
        });
    })->when($filters['category'] ?? false, function ($query, $category) {
        $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('slug', $category);
        });
    });
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping

> You should always group `orWhere` calls in order to avoid unexpected behavior when global scopes are applied.

Comment: No the search method works okay the filtering does not. I tried your method and it still doesn't work

Comment: What does it mean "it doesn't work"?